Как очищать или сохранять ID и использовать их к конкретной заявке
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
from disnake import TextInputStyle


bot = commands.Bot()

# Кнопки принятия/отказа заявки
class AcceptPlayer(disnake.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, author):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.author = author

    @disnake.ui.button(label = "Принять", style = disnake.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def acceptButton(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: {disnake.AppCmdInter, disnake.ModalInteraction}):
        await inter.send(f"Принят {inter.author.mention}", ephemeral = True)
        AcceptMessage = disnake.Embed(
            title = "Принято"
        )
        await self.author.send(embed = AcceptMessage)
        disnake.Button.disabled = True

    @disnake.ui.button(label = "Отклонить", style = disnake.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def rejectButton(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: {disnake.AppCmdInter, disnake.ModalInteraction}):
        await inter.send(f"Отклонён {inter.author.mention}", ephemeral = True)
        RejectMessage = disnake.Embed(
            title = "Отклонено"
        )
        await self.author.send(embed = RejectMessage)
        disnake.Button.disabled = True
 

# Модальное окно
class Request(disnake.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        components = [
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label = "Никнейм",
                placeholder = "Ваш никнейм",
                custom_id = "Никнейм",
                style = TextInputStyle.short,
                max_length = 15,
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label = "Возраст",
                placeholder = "18 лет",
                custom_id = "Возраст",
                style = TextInputStyle.short,
                max_length = "10"
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label = "О себе",
                placeholder = "Коротко о себе",
                custom_id = "Описание",
                style = TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            ),
            disnake.ui.TextInput(
                label = "Что вы планируете делать?",
                placeholder = "Чем планируете заниматься на сервере?",
                custom_id = "Что будете делать",
                style = TextInputStyle.paragraph,
            ),
        ]
        super().__init__(
            title="Заполнение заявки",
            custom_id="Заявка",
            components=components,
        )
# Обработка ответа, после отправки
    async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
        requestEmbed = disnake.Embed(
            title = "Новая заявка!",
            description = f"**Отправитель: {inter.user.global_name}**",
            color = disnake.Colour.red(), 
        )

        requestEmbed.set_thumbnail(url = inter.user.display_avatar.url)
        for key, value in inter.text_values.items():
            requestEmbed.add_field(
                name = key.capitalize(),
                value = value[:1024],
                inline = False,
            )
        await inter.response.send_message(content="Вы успешно заполнили анкету!", ephemeral=True)
        channel = bot.get_channel(1298632551254196277)
        await channel.send(embed = requestEmbed, view = AcceptPlayer(inter.author))

        requestCallBackEmbed = disnake.Embed(
            title = "Ваша заявка отправлена на рассмотрение!",
            description = "***На рассмотрение заявок уходит до 24-х часов***",
            color = disnake.Colour.purple(),   
        )
        requestCallBackEmbed.set_image(file = disnake.File("reference/static.png"))
        requestCallBackEmbed.set_thumbnail(file = disnake.File("reference/miniature.jpg"))
        await inter.author.send(embed = requestCallBackEmbed)

@bot.slash_command(
        name = "tester"
)
async def tags(inter: disnake.AppCmdInter):
    await inter.response.send_modal(modal = Request())
    

with open("token.env") as file:
    token = file.read()
bot.run(token)



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов? => https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/264178

Руководство для новых пользователей Stack Overflow на русском — пункты 1, 2 и 5
